# How have these equations to calculate a probability distribution been derived

Tags: probability, statistics

I haven't studied any maths since I was at university 20 years ago. Yesterday, however, I came across a pair of equations in an online article about gaming and I couldn't understand how they'd been derived.

Here's the scenario. If we make a single trial of generating a number between 1 and 20, there's an even 5% chance of getting any given number. Therefore to get "at least", say, a 11, you can just add up the percentages and subtract them from 100: 100 - (5% x 10) (because 1 is the minimum, not zero) = 50%.

What happens, though, if you make two trials and take either the highest or the lowest number? How then do you calculate the chance of getting "at least" a certain number? For this, I was given the following equations:

- If taking the highest, it's *1-(1-P)^2*
- If taking the lowest it's *P^2*

It's clear these are correct. Rolling "at least" an 11 when taking the lowest values is therefore 0.5 * 0.5 ... 0,25. But what I want to understand is how someone arrived at these equations without using trial and error.

From the limited maths I can recall, P^2 looks not unlike the binomial distribution formula of μ = np - but of course it's raising the probability to the power of two rather than multiplying by two for two trials.

Can someone please explain to me where these come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $P$ is the probability of getting a number $N$ or greater with one trial.

1)For two trials, if you are taking the lower number, then both results should he greater than $N$. Since the two trials can be assumed to be independent, we have to multiply the two probabilities. Thus we get $P\times P=P^2$

2)Now consider the case of taking higher of the two.
In this case we have to find (1-probability(getting number N or lower in both trials)). This is seen by similar arguments to give $(1-(1-P)^2)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1, X_2$ be the random variables, with the independent uniform discrete distributions on the support $\{1..20\}$ .   Let $k$ be a target number within that support.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(\min\{X_1,X_2\}\geq k) &= \mathsf P(X_1\geq k, X_2\geq k) \tag 1 \\[1ex] &= \mathsf P(X_1\geq k)\mathsf P(X_2\geq k) \tag 2 \\[1ex] &= \mathsf P(X_1\geq k)^2 \tag 3 \\[1ex] &= (1-\mathsf P(X_1<k))^2 \\[1ex] &= (1-\tfrac {k-1}{20})^2 \\[2ex] \mathsf P(\max\{X_1,X_2\}\geq k) &= 1-\mathsf P(X_1<11, X_2<11) \tag 4 \\[1ex] &= 1-(\mathsf P(X_1<k))^2 \tag{2,3} \\[1ex] &= 1 -(\tfrac{k-1}{20})^2
\end{align}$$

By reason that: $(1)$ The minimum of two variable being at least a value is the event as both variables being at least that value, $(2)$ The variables are independent, and $(3)$ identically distributed.

Likewise $(4)$ For the maximum to equal or exceed the value, they cannot both be below it.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret correctly, the question you're asking is: Choosing randomly two numbers between 1 and 20, what is the probability that at least one of them is at least 11?

To answer this, we can look at the three cases where this occurs:

- The first number is less than $11$ and the second is at least 11. The probability of this happening is $\frac{10}{20}\times \frac{10}{20} = \frac{1}{4}$
- The first number is larger than 11 and the second is less than 11. This has the same probability as the previous point, $\frac{1}{4}$
- Both of the numbers are at least 11. The probability is, by a coincidence, $\frac{10}{20} \times \frac{10}{20} = \frac{1}{4}$

All of these events are separate, so the total probability is the sum of these, or $\frac{3}{4}$.
Do you feel you can generalize the case for arbitrary values?